# Why is my carousel with an empty item at the end?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twig, owl-carousel

I have two carousels on my page using owl-carousel. Both show an empty last item. I'm a beginner and I have no idea on how to solve this. Can somebody help me?

I'm using twig to loop trough my php array.

```html
<section id='noticia-carousel' class='pt-0'>
        <div class='container main-container'>
            <div class='owl-carousel owl-theme'>
                {% for noticia in noticias_principais %}
                <div class='box'>
                    <img src='{{noticia.imagem_capa}}' alt='Imagem referente à notícia {{noticia.titulo | striptags}}'>
                    <div class='titulo'>
                        <h4><a href='noticia/{{noticia.id}}'> {{noticia.titulo | striptags}} </a></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}

                <div class="owl-controls">
                    <div class="owl-nav">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='text-center'>
                <button class='btn btn-secondary' onclick="window.location.href='/noticias'">Todas
                    as Notícias </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

```
$('#noticia-carousel .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        items: 2,
        dots: false,
        nav: true,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
        animateOut: 'fadeOut',
        autoplay: true,
        loop: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 4000,
        autoplayHoverPause: true,
        responsiveClass: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                nav: false
            },
            600: {
                items: 1,
                nav: false
            },
            1000: {
                items: 2
            },
            1300: {
                items: 2
            }
        }

    });
```

Here is how it looks right now: https://educacao.ouropreto.mg.gov.br/
Works great, but the last item is empty. I want it to autoplay and loop.

Comment: It looks like you only have 7 items, so the last one is an empty placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `HTML` after your `{% for %}` loop has become an item in your carousel because it is a child of `.owl-carousel`:

```html
<div class="owl-controls">
  <div class="owl-nav"></div>
</div>
```

Remove it and there will be no extra space in the carousel.